# Polymer iron-ajax in repeating template not showing

Tags: polymer-1.0

Please help me out! Data was not showing in the repeating template. Thanks!

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

<dom-module id="list-binding">
<style></style>

<template is="dom-bind">

 <iron-ajax 
    auto
    url="data.json"
    handle-as="json"
    last-response="{{data}}">
 </iron-ajax>

 <!--Binding from API-->
 <div class="list">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
     <paper-icon-item class="listItems">
      <img class="avatar blue" item-icon src="{{item.image}}">
        <paper-item-body two-line>
            <div class="title">{{item.title}}</div>
            <div secondary>{{item.description}}</div>
        </paper-item-body>
    </paper-icon-item>
    </template>
</div>
```

```
<script>

  Polymer({
    is: "list-binding"
  });

</script>

</dom-module
```

Answer (score 0):

Polymer's dom-repeat takes an item and index. Looks like you're missing an index in your example. Here's an example for you.

```html
<dom-module id="my-component">
    <template>
     <iron-ajax
      auto
            url="{{url}}"
            on-response="_dataResponse"
        </iron-ajax>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}" as="item">
   <paper-icon-item class="listItems">
    <img class="avatar blue" item-icon src="{{item.image}}">
    <paper-item-body two-line>
     <div class="title">{{item.title}}</div>
     <div secondary>{{item.description}}</div>
    </paper-item-body>
   </paper-icon-item>
        </template>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
Polymer({
    is: 'my-component',
    properties: {
        data:  Object
    },
    _dataResponse: function(e, detail){
     this.data = detail;
    }
});
</script>
```